# Extending jenkins plugin java

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Hey I'm trying to extend a jenkins plugin, namely test-result-analyzer, when I override extension class and add my overriden action class when run the plugin is added twice(the original version of the plugin and my overriden version). I have added the plugin that I want to extend to maven dependency. Then I've tried to uinstall the original plugin but it get's each time I run the plugin here is my overriden extension class

```
@Extension 
public class IesdTestResultsAnalyzerExtension extends    TestResultsAnalyzerExtension {

@Override
public Collection<? extends Action> createFor(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AbstractProject target) {

    try {
        Jenkins.getInstance().getPlugin("test-result-analyzer").stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final List<TestResultsAnalyzerAction> projectActions = target
            .getActions(TestResultsAnalyzerAction.class);
    final ArrayList<Action> actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
    if (projectActions.isEmpty()) {
        final TestResultsAnalyzerAction newAction = new IesdTestResultAnalyzerAction(target);
        actions.add(newAction);
        return actions;
    } else {
        return projectActions;
    }
}
```

}
My maven dependency

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-results-analyzer</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```